# How to change x axis labels to be more specific in a bar chart with ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, axis-labels, x-axis

I want to change my x-axis so it has more specific values. I want it to still start from 0 but go up to 4 or 5 in 0.5 steps. How do I do this? I only know to rename the labels of the x-axis. I tried the command axes = FALSE and then axis (1, at = seq (...)) etc. but that did not work.

This Is my code so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data.m,
  aes(
    y = reorder(Category, ifelse(variable == "Teacher", value, 0), FUN = sum),
    x = value
  )
) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.6), width = .6
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, group = variable),
    hjust = -0.2, size = 2.5,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, .05, 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", breaks = rev) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(title = "Students and Teachers", x = "Category", y = "Means", fill = NULL)
```

Comment: You can directly set the `breaks` with `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0 ,5 ,0.5))`